# How to select the row in gridview,changes it's color when button in grid is clicked

Tags: asp.net

I have gridview.I have manually added one button in item template for selecting row,and all row are auto-generated.When I click on that one row,that row's color should changes.I don't want autogenerated select button.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `SelectedRowStyle-BackColor` property on a GridView.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this property to change row colour...

// add this to code behind....

```
protected void MyGridView_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{    
    string rowID = String.Empty;    
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)    
    {    
       rowID = "<strong class="highlight"><vb_highlight>row</strong></vb_highlight>"+e.Row.RowIndex;    
       e.Row.Attributes.Add("id","<strong class="highlight"><vb_highlight>row</strong></vb_highlight>"+e.Row.RowIndex);

       e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick","ChangeRowColor(" +"'" + rowID + "'" + ")");

    }    
}
```

// Add this to designer page....

```
<script language ="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';    
    var oldColor = '';

     function ChangeRowColor(rowID)    
     {

         var <strong class="highlight">color</strong> = document.getElementById(rowID).style.backgroundColor;    
        if(<strong class="highlight">color</strong> != 'yellow')    
        oldColor = <strong class="highlight">color</strong>;    
         if(<strong class="highlight">color</strong> == 'yellow')    
                document.getElementById(rowID).style.backgroundColor = oldColor;   
        else 
          document.getElementById(rowID).style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';    
       }    
  </script>
```

I hope it will helps you..

Comment: Thanks errorstacks,for ur help.What is <vb_highlight>.I am writing code C#.net.I am getting syntax error at this point(Add ;).onclick is an event of button which is present in gridview.What to write in <asp:button Id = "button1" runat ="server"/>